# Attaching f:ajax to h:panelGroup

Tags: ajax, jsf-2

Whenever I try to attach a `f:ajax` to `h:panelGroup` I get an error:

> Parent is not composite component or
>   of type ClientBehaviorHolder

I used to be able to do it with Richfaces and JSF 1.2. 
Is there a workaround? Should I bring in Richfaces 4.0?

It's odd since it's obviously possible (I do it with jQuery for client side actions)

**UPDATE**
Richfaces 4.0 won't help. Tried it and get the same error.

Code Sample:

```
<li>
  <f:param value="#{contact.getUUID}" name="currContactUUID" /> 
  <f:ajax event="click" onevent="console.log('Event Happend in panelgroup')" >
    <h:panelGroup styleclass="contacts_tab_contacts_list_quickview_box">
        <h:outputText value="#{contact.firstName} #{contact.familyName}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
  </ajax>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That shouldn't be possible for a panelGroup. [`f:ajax`](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html) can only be used for components that implement the [javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorHolder](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html) interface and `h:panelGroup` doesn't.

You can wrap your components inside the panelGroup with a surrounding ajax tag:

```
<f:ajax>
 ... (your components here)
</f:ajax>
```

Comment: I don't get the compilation problem but nothing happends when I click the panelgroup. Any Idea? (Code Updated in question)

Comment: Try to put `f:ajax` inside the panelGroup.

Comment: Thanks. I started a new question for this issue. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095646/fajax-not-working