# f:ajax not working

Tags: html, ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I have trouble getting `f:ajax` to work on a `h:panelGroup`.
Here's what i'm doing:

JSF code:

```
<h:panelGroup id="contacts_tab_contacts_list_list">
    <h:form>
    <ul>
        <c:forEach items="#{currentDevice.contacts}" var="contact">
            <li>
                <f:ajax event="click" onevent="logcheck()">
                    <h:panelGroup layout="block" 
                                styleclass="contacts_tab_contacts_list_quickview_box"  >
                            <h:outputText value="#{contact.firstName} #{contact.familyName}" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:ajax> 

                <f:ajax event="click" onevent="logcheck()">
                    <f:param value="#{contact.getUUID}" name="currContactUUID" />
                    <h:commandButton value="#{contact.firstName} #{contact.familyName}" 
                    styleclass="contacts_tab_contacts_list_quickview_box" />
                </f:ajax>
            </li>
        </c:forEach>
    </ul>
    </h:form>
</h:panelGroup>
```

What it looks like on the web page: (Ignore silly formatting :-) )
[image]

And finally, what the source of the page looks like:

```
<li>
    Name - 35 Family - 35
    <input 
        id="j_id594943238_6609edf4:j_id594943238_6609ec58" 
        name="j_id594943238_6609edf4:j_id594943238_6609ec58" 
        type="submit" 
        value="Name - 35 Family - 35" 
        onclick=".. removed .." /> 
</li>
```

(Notice how the `h:panelgroup` was "swallowed" by the `li` element.)

I can click the `h:commandButton` and it works properly.
Nothing happends when I click the text and it makes sense because, as it seems from looking in the source, the `h:panelGroup` along with the `f:ajax` have disappeared!

That's it. Sorry for the length but I wanted to get all the details out.
Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the panelGroup will be swallowed since there is only one component inside. Maybe jsf optimizes it.

Then there is only the `h:outputText` left and this [component](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/html/HtmlOutputText.html) doesn't implement the  [javax.faces.component.behavior.ClientBehaviorHolder](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/behavior/ClientBehaviorHolder.html) interface which is required for a component that gets ajax attached.

You could use `h:outputLink` or maybe `h:outputLabel` instead.

Comment: Tnx! So, as a follow up, How would you make a clickable `div` that can contain images and text? (Meaning, the whole div section would be clickable, similar to a `h:commandbutton` but with more control over content and styling.

Answer (score 0):

did small POC for ajax may be useful for others

This chunk will show that we can call managed bean method and  Ajax together and it works using JSF2.0

```
<h:form>     
  <h:inputText id="comments" value="#{photoManagedBean.name}"></h:inputText>

  <h:commandButton value="Comments Input" >
    <f:ajax execute="comments" listener="#{photoManagedBean.saveComments()}" render="displayRecentComments" />

   </h:commandButton>
   <br/>

   <table width="600" border="0"  height="80">
     <td>
       <h:outputText id="displayRecentComments" value="#{photoManagedBean.name}"/>
     </td>
   </table>
 </h:form>
```

ManagedBean:

```
public void saveComments() { //ur code//}
```