# Invoke a backing bean action method on click of a <h:panelGroup layout="block">

Tags: jsf-2

How can I make the `mainDiv` clickable and invoke a backing bean action method?

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="mainDiv">
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="float:left;">
        <h:outputText value="#{messageItem.sendBy.registerName}"/>
    </h:panelGroup>
    <h:panelGroup layout="block" style="float:right;">
        <h:outputText value="#{messageItem.sendDate}">
            <f:convertDateTime pattern="HH:mm"/>
        </h:outputText>
    </h:panelGroup>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Comment: Have a look at this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8160494/how-to-make-a-whole-div-clickable-in-html-and-css-without-javascript

Comment: in Jquery is possible but in JSF events don't know how

Comment: This as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6095646/fajax-not-working

Comment: Ah .. maybe i will just use Remote in JSF

Comment: I feel it won't work when nested Divs present.

Comment: it work i just did this 
<h:form>
<div onclick="test()">

</div>
<p:remoteCommand name="remoteName" actionListener="#{test.testfunction()}"/>
</h:form>

<script>function test(){
  remoteName();
}
</script>

in my bean like this

public void testfunction(){
         System.out.println("hello");
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way would be to wrap its contents in a `<h:commandLink>`, if necessary with `<f:ajax>`. Use CSS `display:block` to let the link span the entire div.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="mainDiv">
    <h:commandLink action="#{bean.action}" style="display:block;">
        <f:ajax />
        ...
    </h:commandLink>
</h:panelGroup>
```

Or, given your question history you're using PrimeFaces, you can also use `<p:remoteCommand>`.

```
<h:panelGroup layout="block" id="mainDiv" onclick="functionName()">
    ...
</h:panelGroup>
<p:remoteCommand name="functionName" action="#{bean.action}" />
```

Comment: @Ced: That was later introduced/fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `f:ajax` on `panelGroup`

```
<h:panelGroup>
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{adminPanel.test}"></f:ajax>
    xxx
</h:panelGroup>
```

resulting html :

```
<span id="j_idt169" onclick="mojarra.ab(this,event,'click',0,0)">
    xxx
</span>
```